# Working with nested Preference screens in different xml files

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an outer PreferenceScreen, which contains some preferences and a nested PreferenceScreen with some preferences. If I want to keep all of them in one file, it is simple:

```
<PreferenceScreen>
    <PreferenceScreen>
        ....
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I want to include preferences from another preference file. How do I achieve that?

I tried using `<include layout="">` but include is not available under PreferenceScreen

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this on `PreferencesActivity`:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.Main_Preferences);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.Additional_Preferences);
```

Comment: the include layout tag is not available under PreferenceScreen

Comment: How do I set additional preferences to be children of one element of main preferences?

Comment: Also, I was thinking there should be some way of doing it through XML.

Comment: @shiladitya you can use multiple Preferences Activity, than set child prefrerences based on Main Prefrences Activity